# Can this ORACLE query be further fine tuned to improve performance?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

```
SELECT P.OBJECT_NAME||'.'||P.PROCEDURE_NAME,P.OBJECT_ID, R.IN_OUT,COUNT(*)
  FROM ALL_PROCEDURES@ORCL P, ALL_ARGUMENTS@ORCL R
 WHERE P.OWNER = 'SWPROEAIDB3'
   AND P.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
   AND P.PROCEDURE_NAME IS NOT NULL
   AND P.OBJECT_ID=R.OBJECT_ID
   AND P.OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID
                         FROM ALL_ARGUMENTS@ORCL
                        WHERE OWNER='SWPROEAIDB3'
                        GROUP BY OBJECT_ID
                       HAVING COUNT(*)=2 ) 
 GROUP BY P.OBJECT_NAME||'.'||P.PROCEDURE_NAME,
          P.OBJECT_ID,
          R.IN_OUT
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

I am looking for all such procedures for the schema - SWPROEAIDB3 who have only 2 arguments in them and must contain one IN and one OUT.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please check execution plan with row source statistics to see where the time is going, it looks like this should be a fully remote query but there’s a chance something has tripped it into making it distributed, be sure to check that. You should be able to achieve the results without the extra join to all_arguments with a bit of analytic functions. Which user is your DB link using - you may be better of using the user_ versions of these views, all_ typically have funny security filters which cause havoc for the optimizer. If you have to use all_ then a with clause (to materialize) should help